# RFC: Lightweight C++ 2D array template with runtime dinemsions

Tags: c++

Any comments, critiques or questions about this? I'm using this as the base for a few rectangular board based toy programs like Conway's life and snake. Usage includes configuration of board size at runtime, hence the type doesn't carry size info, only the instances.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename type>
class Array2D {
   int y;
   type *data;
public:
   // We can't do a copy since we don't know
   // what size to allocate the array.
   Array2D(const Array2D&) = delete;
   Array2D& operator=(const Array2D&) = delete;

   Array2D(Array2D&& move) noexcept :
      y(std::exchange(move.y, 0)),
      data(std::exchange(move.data, nullptr)) {}

   Array2D& operator=(Array2D&& move) noexcept {
      std::swap(y, move.y);
      std::swap(data, move.data);
   }

   Array2D( int _x, int _y ) : y(_y) {
      data = new type[_x*y];
   }

   type const *operator[](int i) const {
      return data + (i * y);
   }

   type *operator[](int i) {
      return data + (i * y);
   }

   ~Array2D() {
      delete[] data;
   }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of usage such as a unit test case?

Answer (score 3):

### Overall

It's fine as far as it goes.

I don't see anything wrong with the implementation.

Note: Since you use none checked version of `operator[]` you should have the ability to validate that your inputs are correct. So your array needs the ability to return the dimensions of the array in both the x and y dimensions so the code can validate the inputs when required.

### Next Step

Currently this is not a container.

There are a few more requirements to make this a standards compliant container. If you want to go this direction.

see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container

### Some improvements:

User defined Types (and by extension template types) should always have an initial capitol letter. This is for humans so we can easily distiguish types from objects:

```
template<typename type>
```

I don't like this as now type looks like an object to me when I read it in the code.

Put the destructor next to the constructors.
When code reviewing I want to make sure that your destructor releases the resources correctly as I read. Not scroll back when I find the destructor at the bottom. Also they logically group together.

Why is none copy?
I don't see the logic in that.

Add a swap method (noexcept) and swap free standing function. That comes in handy when interacting with the standard library functions.

It would be nice to simply loop over an array:

```
Array2D<int>   data = get2DArray();

for(auto const& val: data) {
    std::cout << val << " ";
}
```

The ability to extract rows to loop over would also be nice (this is an alternative to the above).

```
for(auto const& row: data) {
    for(auto const& val: row) {
        std::cout << val << " "; 
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

You have the none checked `operator[]` implemented fine. But sometimes it is nice to have checked versions so add the method `at()` that does the same thing but validates its input first.

This is very C like `type const *object` The `*` placed next to the object is a standard C convention but in C++ the convention is the opposite and (by tradition) you put the `*` next to the type rather than the objet (as it is part of the type information).

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple of comments here.

#### Move "yayy" but copy "nay"?

I do understand why you don't keep the size information as a template parameter on the type, but is there a real reason why not to keep it on the instance? I mean, why do you only have `int y` rather than `int x, y`?

I think this:

```
// We can't do a copy since we don't know
// what size to allocate the array.
```

Is quite problematic. Not having a copying mechanism is (most of the time) due to resource sharing not being practical in the context. But for matrices, it seems very intuitive to copy them. That's one thing to think of, although your design might require (or be satisfied) with uncopyable matrices.

Another argument here is the way you want invalid access to the array to fail. Currently, it seems that you're going to access your array in the following way: `arr[2][5]`. What happens if your array has a size of 5*5 but you access it on `arr[6][10]`? That's right, a segmentation fault.

You do want your type to "fail safely", whether that's by emitting an exception or returning a default value and logging the error. Maybe today you handle calls to the array in the following way

```
int x = 5, y = 5;
Array2D arr(x, y);
// ...

int requiredX = ..., requiredY = ..., value = 0;
if (requiredX < x && requiredY < y) {
    value = arr[requiredX][requiredY];
}
```

In this case, you do have to manage your X and Y. Why not do it inside your class?

The only other way I see to properly guarantee memory safety is using a single pair of `const` (or `#define`d) height and width for your array. And in this case, why not include it in the type anyway, right? (not really, but I'm just making a point)

Anyway, I suggest putting the "height" of the matrix as a member. After all, it's just 4/8 more bytes and it's going to save you a fortune.

#### Why is your size signed?

Your array cannot have negative indices, right? Make your `x` and `y` members of an unsigned type (preferably the pointer type on the system, which is `size_t`)

#### Destructor may throw

`delete[]` is not a safe operation in C++, it may throw. Now, it might be due to memory corruption around your `data` member, and it really *shouldn't* happen, but it may. Destructors shouldn't throw, says the law. So make sure it doesn't throw. You can just `try{} catch(...) {}` around the delete statement and log the error if anything happens.

#### Use a middleware type for array access?

As I mentioned earlier, you don't seem to restrict access to the array. The most idiomatic way, in my opinion, is to make a middleware mini-type to reference rows in the array. Have a simple implementation (ignoring any ownership discipline and move semantics):

```
template <class T>
class ArrayRow {
public:
    ArrayRow(T* ptr, size_t size) : .... {}

    T& operator[](size_t index) && {
        if (index >= row_size) throw ...
        return row[row_size];
    }

private:
    T* row;
    size_t row_size;
}
```

Of course, implement `const` aware access to this class, etcetera etcetera. The array should implement member access in the following way (again, ignoring many other concerns)

```
ArrayRow operator[](size_t index) {
    if (index >= x) throw ...
    return ArrayRow(data + y * index, y);
}
```

The only atrocity we are afraid to commit in this case is thus:

```
ArrayRow row(nullptr, 0);
{
    Array2D arr(x, y);
    // ...
    row = arr[3];
}

int x = row[2]; // This happens after arr was released
```

This can be solved by restricting assignments to ArrayRow, and having that `&&` qualifier on the `operator[]` function (that requires the ArrayRow to be an rvalue or xvalue reference, practically saying it has to be the return value of a function, such as `Array2D::operator[]`.

#### Just a couple more notes

1. I would implement the non-`const` array access in terms of the `const` one (cast `*this` to `const Array2D<T>`, then call the `[]` operator, then cast the result back to non-`const`. That way you don't have code repetition and make it easier to change the way array access is implemented.
2. I would create a non-throwing swap method and just call it from the assignment operator. Although it's not highly relevant to your case, I would still look at [Why you should create a non-throwing swap() function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-throwing_swap)
3. As a style note, I would put your private members in the bottom of the class declaration and not at the top (are the clients of this class really going to be interested in the private fields more than in the public interface?)
4. Also a style note, but consider initializing stuff with uniform initialization syntax `{}` rather than default initialization syntax `()`. If your `Array2D<T>`'s `T`s are not going to have a constructor which takes an `std::initializer_list`, it's not really error-prone and generally preferable.

Comment: There is just an error on destructors. You misunderstand the meaning behind destructors': cannot-throw. They are implicitly `noexcept` - which means that it won't throw an exception. It doesn't mean that code inside must not. It can, it which case the program will terminate instead of unwinding the stack. So his destructor is perfectly fine.

Comment: If you're fine with your program terminating uncleanly... Well, it's fine, and maybe on this occasion, it works fine, too. But conceptually, you don't really want your program to exit without cleaning after itself (what if it left a lock file on the file-system that needs to be deleted?). Even if it may be legal to throw an exception in a destructor, I would argue that you really really _should_ not.

Comment: if `delete[]` throws there then the program is already corrupted beyond recovery. Adding a-too-late try/catch doesn't help it. It might even prevent programmer from detecting bugs. Since probably program is already in UB territory - doing one thing might result in something else entirely. It is generally advisable to simply shutdown before any more harm is done.

Comment: `You do want your type to "fail safely", whether that's by emitting an exception or returning a default value and logging the error. ` No. The standard pattern (in C++) is that `operator[]` is not safe (but fast) and you should check before use. If you want a checking version you add the method `at(int index)` this would be a checked version. `for(int loop = 0;loop < vec.size();++loop) {std::cout << vec[loop];}` Why would you want to force a check here? You have guaranteed that loop is always in range and thus a check is inefficient.

Comment: `So make sure it doesn't throw.` This is really bad advice. If the memory is corrupted and this is causign an exception then you have a much bigger problem. You should not catch the exception but allow it to propogate. If this is inside the destructor fine you will cause the application to exit but in the situation where you have corrupted memory this is the most desirable result.

Comment: `Use a middleware type for array access?` If you want checked access add the `at()` method. Leave `operator[]` unchecked.

Comment: `The only atrocity we are afraid to commit in this case is thus:` You can solve that by making the constructor private and only accessible from `Array2D`. Thus it can never be constructed incorrectly (ie nullptr).

Comment: `I would implement the non-const array access in terms of the const one` Sure you could but in this simple case not worth it.

Comment: `As a style note, I would put your private members in the bottom of the class declaration and not at the top` Completely disagree. As a style thing put the private member **variables** at the top (so you can easily see them in conjunction with the constructor. **BUT** yes put the private member methods at the bottom.

Comment: Re 4), How would I use a uniform initializer here? The constructor muist do the real work of allocating the memory?

Comment: @MartinYork Thanks for the helpful comments, some which I agree with and some which I don't. I learnt a few things anyway. Will edit my answer with some of your advice

Comment: @PeteFordham If I'm not mistaken, you can initialize `data` in the constructor with `: data{new type[_x * y]}`

Comment: OK, I see that that works, but what makes this inherently better than braces?

Comment: @PeteFordham: It's not inherently better in this case (its the same). But if you use the '{}' syntax you can use it consistently everywhere (even when you want to be explicit about using the default constructor). On the other hand the '()' syntax can not be used consistently everywhere. In a few situations (see most vexing parse) you need to do some tricks to get it working correctly. In programming consistency is considered a good thing.